# Filezilla FTP server - set upload location on file server

Tags: ftps, filezilla, ftp-server

I'm setting up a FTPS server and want to upload files to File server(NAS drive). I mapped the drive and tried 'drive letter' and '\serverpath\', But during the transfer its shows failed transfer error. File transfer works for local disks.

Has anyone came accross with the issue to upload files on file server(NAS drive) using FTPS? Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Windows 'System' account can't access network shared drive, So i had to run filezilla server service under network user and then it worked.